# Make reference to a figure

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

I'm working on Overleaf and I searched how to make a reference to a figure but it's not working, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
    Contenu de la figure.
\end{figure}

Je veux faire référence à la Figure~\ref{fig:enter-label}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example works fine for me

Comment: Did you compile it twice?

Comment: I just want to add that Overleaf gives an example of how to proceed but it's not working either on my browser; here's the link: https://www.overleaf.com/project/65c607300a2bdd889c5d42c8

Comment: Seems to work fine on overleaf, too https://www.overleaf.com/read/njpmnvyfwgjh#a264fc

Comment: what do you mean by "it is not working"? What do see or do that doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: I mean I expect the reference to be clickable and redirect to the figure mentionned

Comment: @avirsty Use the `hyperref` package

Comment: It works with hyperref now but I don't understand why this is not working without, why having a ref as here: https://www.overleaf.com/project/65c607300a2bdd889c5d42c8 if it's not for having a clickable link leading to the reference? I don't get it.

Comment: @avirsty Traditionally, documents were printed on paper. The readers of the document would read the number and flip pages with their hands to look at the figure with the corresponding number.

Comment: @avirsty - "I don't understand why this is not working without [`hyperref`]." TeX was designed in the 1970s and 1980s, i..e., long before Tim Berners-Lee came up with the first prototype of the World Wide Web, and many more years before the first working version of the `hyperref` package appeared on the scene. Is it really that challenging and burdensome to have to write `\usepackage{hyperref}` in the preamble of your LaTeX document?

Comment: I suggest to consolidate background and solutions given here in the comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution based on the discussion in the comments :).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref} % <-- Solution

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
    %Contenu de la figure. % <-- Removed, because I do not see the reason for it.
\end{figure}

SDome Frenmch text that I cannot understand Figure~\ref{fig:enter-label}.
\end{document}
```